# How the print function works in an if-statement condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A Summer Midterm question, still cannot wrap my head around it,

If someone can explain it to me I'll be glad

```py
if print(8):
    print(10000)
```

It prints 8 and i don't understand why?

Comment: Is 8 the entire output? Either way, it prints 8 simply because the print method is being called. If it also prints 10000, it’s because print(8) has a true value, if not, print(8) has a false value

Comment: @wakeel: it should not print `10000`, since `print(..)` returns `None`, and `None` has as truthiness `False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if print(8):
    print(10000)
```

Things the interpreter does:

1. Run `print(8)` -> you see `8` in your terminal
2. Take the function's return value -> `print()` always returns `None`
3. Place the return value to the condition of the if-statement
4. Evaluate:

```
if None:
    print(10000)
```

5. Since `None` is a falsy value, it will not go inside the if-block
6. Exit the program

Answer (score 3):

An `if` statement will first evaluate the expression next to the `if` keyword. So `print(8)`. `print(8)` will thus print `8` to the standard output channel, and return `None`.

The `if` statement will then evaluate the "truthiness" of that value. The truthiness of `None` is `False`. Thus means that the condition in the `if` condition is not truthfull, and hence the body (`print(10000)`) is *not* evaluated. It will thus print `8`, but *not* `10000`.

The documentation has a [section *Truth Value Testing* [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). As the documentation says:

> - constants defined **to be false**: **`None`** and `False`.